# TensorFlow operation 'tf.train.match_filenames_once ' not working

Tags: file-io, tensorflow

I have following code for reading files names from directory:

```
directory = "C:/pics/*.csv"
file_names=tf.train.match_filenames_once(directory)
print(file_names)
<tf.Variable 'matching_filenames_1:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=string_ref>

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(file_names))
```

When I run session I am getting the following error:
" Attempting to use uninitialized value matching_filenames"

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a subtle distinction between what TF considers global and local variables. This code works as you expect

```
import tensorflow as tf

directory = "*.*"
file_names = tf.train.match_filenames_once(directory)

init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(file_names))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me a lot of frustration. It would have been great if they mentioned this in the documentation for 'tf.train.match_filenames_once'.

Comment: can you please detail what is that distinction ? How can we know when a variable is global or local for TF ?